# Where are the rules for "magic" pools?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e

Encountered a problem in a game the other night, no one had written down their "magic" pool. I looked under quick character creation sections, and may have skimmed over it, but couldn't find it. By "magic" I mean supernatural specific for using powers e.g, vitae, essence?, glamour, mana, pyros, etc (newer games should be included I just don't have them). I'd like to have the answer be a reference, and include page numbers. Noticing that their's some information on this at the bottom of the character sheet? for example vitae 1d10, but it seems to me that there's a max for these pools? the max is what I'm trying to find out.

Answer (score 1):

In the nWoD books using the **World of Darkness** core book, the pools of magical fuel are linked to the Power Stat (Blood Potency, Primal Urge, Gnosis, etc.). The limits are found in a common chart — in Requiem, it's on page 99; in Awakening, page 76.

To find this information, seek out the "Traits" section — it's often just before the Merits section — or, if using a PDF, search out "Max" in the text.

The following information is true for Requiem, Forsaken, Awakening, Created, and Lost.

POWER STAT. MAX FUEL

1. 10
2. 11
3. 12
4. 13
5. 14
6. 15
7. 20
8. 30
9. 50
10. 100

Comment: yeah, I'm aware they're based on the power stat, but for example I read up on Blood Potency saw where it says the total vitae is based on that, and yet still don't see where it says how much vitae. I know it's not 1.

Comment: @xenoterracide Do you have the book handy? There's a chart on page 99 of Requiem that lists that information.

Comment: DOH! I've been overlooking the Max part of that as something else

Comment: Blood & Smoke updates this and is on p90

Comment: @xenoterracide Many things that are true under [tag:nwod] have changed under GMC updates, but that's how you tagged it. :)

Comment: the point of this question is to help people find this stuff, since it's not nicely referenced under character quick creation, and until I found it I wouldn't know if it would have updated.

Comment: also the charts are different for each, mage for example can spend at a different rate. Though my question was about pool size not spend rate.